# Google Maps event that is called when all visible map tiles are loaded

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios, google-maps, mkmapview

Is there a way to programmatically determine when Google Maps is done loading visible image tiles in an MKMapView? I would like to take a screenshot of a view in an iPad app that has a Google Map in it, but I don't know how long to wait before taking the screenshot.

I can't seem to find an event that triggers when tiles are done loading so the screenshot will actually have images in it, instead of a blank gray background.

Answer (score 0):

This method: 
- (void)mapViewDidFinishLoadingMap:(MKMapView *)mapView

in the [MKMapViewDelegate protocol](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapViewDelegate_Protocol/MKMapViewDelegate/MKMapViewDelegate.html) will do that for you.

Comment: That event is not fired in all cases. It's very inconsistent, and seems to depend on whether map tiles are cached locally, at least in iOS 4.