# How to tell when all visible tiles have fully loaded?

Tags: javascript, events, leaflet, dom-events

Is there an event (or other method) to detect when all *visible* tiles have been downloaded and displayed with leaflet? (Similar to [Google Maps event that is called when all visible map tiles are loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5858863/google-maps-event-that-is-called-when-all-visible-map-tiles-are-loaded), but for leaflet instead)

Comment: What about http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.2.0.html#map-whenready?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Solved. Bind the "load" event on the tile layer. Example:

```
var tile_layer=L.tileLayer(tile_url,{
  attribution: "Map data &copy; <a href='http://openstreetmap.org'>OpenStreetMap</a> "+
    "contributors, <a href='http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/'>CC-BY-SA</a>.",
  maxZoom: 18
});
tile_layer.addTo(map);
tile_layer.on("load",function() { console.log("all visible tiles have been loaded") });
```

Comment: Very useful, thanks. Some answers elsewhere mention adding the 'load' listener at the map level but it fires almost immediately.

Answer (score 27):

The list of TileLayer events according to [the leaflet documentation](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#tilelayer-loading):

**loading**     *Event* - Fired when the tile layer starts loading tiles.

**load**    *Event* -   Fired when the tile layer loaded all visible tiles.

**tileloadstart**   *TileEvent* -   Fired when a tile is requested and starts loading.

**tileload**    *TileEvent* -   Fired when a tile loads.

**tileunload**  *TileEvent* -   Fired when a tile is removed (e.g. when you have unloadInvisibleTiles on).

Comment: For a full list of map events, see http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-events.